# Unable to create the Project using Taza from cmd prompt

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

When I try to create the project from cmd prompt using *taza* gem, I am running into the following error:

> cannot load such file -- i18n (LoadError)

I have even updted the gems but still getting the same error.

My system Specifications:

> Windows 7
>
> ruby version:1.9.3

Logs:

```
D:\>taza Example
You don't have i18n installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile
and run bundle install
D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- i18n (LoadError)
 from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
 from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
_support/i18n.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
_support/inflector/transliterate.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
 _ support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active  
 _support/xml_mini.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
 _support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
 _support/duration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
 _support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
 n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
 _support/time.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
  n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
  n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active
  _support/all.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
  n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
  n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubigen-1.5.8/lib/rubigen.rb:4:
   in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
   n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
   n `require'
    from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taza-0.9.1.2/bin/taza:4:in `<to
   p (required)>'
    from D:/Ruby193/bin/taza:23:in `load'
    from D:/Ruby193/bin/taza:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: yes its a gem .........and also there is a framework too

Comment: Did you see that `You don't have i18n installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile`. make sure that `i18n` gem is installed, check it in the `Gemfile.lock`
did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: D:\>bundle install
'bundle' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.      i got these error when i try to run the bundle install

Comment: install *bundler* gem: `gem install bundler`

Comment: D:\>gem install bundle
Fetching: bundler-1.5.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: bundle-0.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.5.1
Successfully installed bundle-0.0.1
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.5.1...
Installing ri documentation for bundle-0.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.5.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundle-0.0.1...

D:\>bundle install
Bundler::GemfileNotFound

Comment: I dont know is there in Windows `which` command. if yes type `which gem`, and `which bundle`, `which ruby`. And type also `ruby -v`

Comment: i checked those ....its the same error

Comment: show the output here...

Comment: no i dont use that and the output i have commented above...........

Comment: you dont provided the output for commands `which gem`, and `which bundle`, and `which ruby` if any. Well, the error  `Bundler::GemfileNotFound` is rised up when you call to bundler app when bunlder gem is installed for other env. at first try to reset your ruby env. Have you use the mingw/cygwin env, or just pure ruby ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install the il8n gem:

```
gem install i18n
```

(Run the above from your command prompt to install the gem.)

Comment: yaa i did  these and the issue got resolved and now facing new error like when i try to run the spec i am running into following error          D:\Example>rake -T
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup